# Decompile a .NET Assembly without ILSpy

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling

Is it possible to decompile a .NET Assembly in C# **without** external executables like ILSpy? Libraries, which could be used in my program would be great.
Can you give me any advice to do this?

Comment: Try [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

Comment: What's your definition of external executables? Why do you want to avoid them? You probably can use the ILSpy assemblies directly, without creating the ILSpy GUI. Is that OK?

Comment: If it wasn't possible, how do you think tools such as ILSpy came into existence? Divine creation?

Comment: If you mean external, by non-installed with Microsoft....have you tried? ILDasm?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.80).aspx You can run the tool from within Visual Studio: http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18784

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want source code of it, and integrate to your app. You can check 2 project bellow:

- Mono.cecil: https://github.com/jbevain/cecil
- ILSpy: https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy